# wikipedia doesn't like file_get_contents

Tags: php, proxy, file-get-contents, wikipedia

I use the PHP function `file_get_contents` as a proxy to fetch websites on two different web hosts.

It works for all websites except Wikipedia.

It gives me this output every time:

> WIKIMEDIA FOUNDATION
>   Error
>   Our servers are currently experiencing a technical problem. This is probably temporary and
>   should be fixed soon. Please try again in a few minutes.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: can you show the code you are using?

Comment: It might be useful to use a program like Wireshark to compare a request from this proxy with a request that does work, like from an un-proxied browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably not passing the correct User-Agent. See [**here**](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).

You should pass a context to `file_get_contents`:

- [PHP: `file_get_contents` - Manual](http://php.net/file_get_contents)
- [PHP: `stream_context_create` - Manual](http://php.net/stream_context_create)

Comment: thnx, 'user_agent'=> $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  was the solution

Answer (score 1):

Wikimedia Foundation [policy](//meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) is to block requests with non-descriptive or missing User-Agent headers because these tend to originate from misbehaving scripts. "PHP" is one of the blacklisted values for this header.

You should [change the default User-Agent header](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuick_start_guide#Identifying_your_client) to one that identifies your script and how the system administrators can contact you if necessary:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'MyCoolTool/1.1 (http://example.com/MyCoolTool/; MyCoolTool@example.com)');
```

Of course, be sure to change the name, URL, and e-mail address rather than copying the code verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia requires a `User-Agent` HTTP header be sent with the request. By default, `file_get_contents` does not send this.

You should use `fsockopen`, `fputs`, `feof` and `fgets` to send a full HTTP request, or you may be able to do it with cURL. My personal experience is with the `f*` functions, so here's an example:

```
$attempts = 0;
do {
    $fp = @fsockopen("en.wikipedia.org",80,$errno,$errstr,5);
    $attempts++;
} while(!$fp && $attempts < 5);
if( !$fp) die("Failed to connect");
fputs($fp,"GET /wiki/Page_name_here HTTP/1.0\r\n"
     ."Host: en.wikipedia.org\r\n"
     ."User-Agent: PHP-scraper (your-email@yourwebsite.com)\r\n\r\n");
$out = "";
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $out .= fgets($fp);
}
fclose($fp);
list($head,$body) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$out);
$head = explode("\r\n",$head);
list($http,$status,$statustext) = explode(" ",array_shift($head),3);
if( $status != 200) die("HTTP status ".$status." ".$statustext);
echo $body;
```

Comment: Why do you prefer f* functions over curl?

Comment: Because I prefer to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: What I mean is that I like to write my code and have it do what I tell it to do. This is why I prefer `socket_create`/`bind`/`listen` over `socket_create_listen`. It just makes more sense for me to be in control of every step. I guess it's just my paranoia after losing years of data to code that I couldn't make heads nor tails off because it was so convoluted and pointles.

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL for this:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://wikipedia.org');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have already "tried again in a few minutes".

Next thing you could try is using cURL instead of `file_get_contents`, and setting the user-agent one of a common browser.

If it still doesn't work, it should at least give you some more info.